# Single json key have to display multiple strings with line breaks

Tags: html, json, key

I have single json key that has multiple lines. Now these values has to be displayed in HTML with line breaks. But line breaks are not coming.

This is my json key. I want rule 1,2,3 to be displayed in HTML with proper breaks.
`"componentValue":" 1)Please ensure that password is between 6 and 15 characters in length,2)Password should have atleast one digit,3)Password should contain an upper case. ",`

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS rule to container you put the text with new lines in:

```
.container {
    white-space: pre;
}
```